# Getting the URL of a Ruby on Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a helper in my Ruby on Rails app for the unsecure_url

```
def unsecure_url
  "http://localhost:3000/"
end
```

However, this is wrong when it the app is live.  I just put the app online and would like to do something like this:

```
def unsecure_url
  if is_production
    production_url # <-- any way to determine this dynamically?
  else
    "http://localhost:3000/"
  end
end
```

Any advice on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is you just want to get the URl of the current page?

```
def unsecure_url
  if is_production
    production_url = request.request_uri
  else
    "http://localhost:3000/"
  end
end
```

Comment: Pretty close. I found out that request.request_uri is depreciated in RoR 3 -- use request.fullpath instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the full path you could use `root_url`. That'll give you the http://localhost:3000/ part.  If you want any path info like /blogs/123 you'll need the request methods already mentioned.